# Android Studio 4.0 app run fail 1 times out of 2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

It is a bug I'm experiencing since a few days, since I migrated to Android Studio 4.0, but it seems not to happen all the times.

When it happen, running the app will work 1 times out of 2. When I hit Alt+F9 for the first time it do nothing, Android Studio say the app is built and installed successfully, but it doesn't show up on my phone, if I hit Alt+F9 again, then it work as intended. After that the next Alt+F9 will not work, and the one after will work, and the one after will not ...

Is anyone experiencing the same issue and have found what exact condition that trigger this bug?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same, seems clearly a new bug in Android Studio.